# How to Delete List Item in a Custom Page?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom Dashboard page (Dashboard.aspx) that I made - it is not located inside the list, rather inside Pages folder.

I created this Dashboard to replace SharePoint's default "AllItems.aspx".

However, I could not replicate the onClick event of "Delete Item" from the SharePoint default list view.

**Can anyone provide code snippets of how to delete a list item from a custom page?**

[image: Trying to delete this list item with the ID 180.]

P.S.: My custom page already has the ID and List Name. I appreciate your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I have a JS library called "SPAPI_Lists", which is from SharePoint Services, I believe.

It provides a function called `quickDeleteListItem(listName, listItemId)`.

Code looks like this:

```
var urlThatContainsList = 'http://www.samplesite.com/sample';
var listName = 'Sample List';
var listItemId = 3;
new SPAPI_Lists(urlThatContainsList).quickDeleteListItem(listName, listItemId);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function provided by Microsoft is this one:

```
function DeleteListItem() {
  ULSrLq: ;
  if (!IsContextSet()) return;
  var b = currentCtx,
      e = currentItemID,
      g = currentItemFSObjType,
      c = L_STSRecycleConfirm_Text;
  if (!b.RecycleBinEnabled || b.ExternalDataList) c = L_STSDelConfirm_Text;
  if (b.HasRelatedCascadeLists && b.CascadeDeleteWarningMessage != null) c = b.CascadeDeleteWarningMessage + c;
  if (confirm(c)) {
      var h = L_Notification_Delete,
          f = addNotification(h, true),
          a = b.clvp;
      if (b.ExternalDataList && a != null) {
          a.DeleteItemCore(e, g, false);
          a.pendingItems = [];
          a.cctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
              ULSrLq: ;
              if (typeof a.rgehs != "undefined") {
                  if (a.rgehs.length == 1 && a.rgehs[0].get_serverErrorCode() == SP.ClientErrorCodes.redirect) {
                      GoToPage(a.rgehs[0].get_serverErrorValue());
                      return
                  }
                  removeNotification(f);
                  a.ShowErrorDialog(RefreshOnDialogClose)
              } else RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
          }, function () {
              ULSrLq: ;
              removeNotification(f);
              typeof a.rgehs != "undefined" && a.ShowErrorDialog()
          })
      } else {
          var d = b.HttpPath + "&Cmd=Delete&List=" + b.listName + "&ID=" + e + "&NextUsing=" + GetSource();
          if (null != currentItemContentTypeId) d += "&ContentTypeId=" + currentItemContentTypeId;
          SubmitFormPost(d)
      }
  }
}
```

With that you should be able to find what you need for your case.

If you use some jQuery/JavaScript in your page, you may also want to check [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) that provides some useful functions (like to get data from a list or to delete an item).

Comment: I am using the "SPAPI_Lists.js", and it has nifty functions in it. I have not seen this one, so I will try and if it works, I'll let you know. Thanks!